# Why can I decrypt a gpg-encrypted file with less?

Tags: gpg

I encrypted a file with my own gpg key.

After reboot, I can view the decrypted content of the gpg file directly with less, but cat/gvim/gedit show binary content.

Why does less have this function? Does it automatic decrypt with gnome-keying?

```
▶ file pw.gpg 
pw.gpg: PGP RSA encrypted session key ....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`less` can use a helper program to decode files for display. This is configured using the `LESSOPEN` environment variable; see

```
echo $LESSOPEN
```

Typically this uses a helper called `lesspipe`.

See the [“input preprocessor” section of the `less` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html#INPUT_PREPROCESSOR) for details.

In your case, the helper uses `gpg` to decrypt the file, and `gpg` gets your key from the agent (the keyring).

Comment: As long as this is a normal process, so good.  I was just worried about the possibility that someone would be so easy to take my contents.

Comment: @utopiceexpress, FYI it is very easy to extract you content by mistake with `less`, for example with the `s` command. Better not use `less` for opening `gpg` files or run it in secure mode. But I don't find a way to run it in secure mode only when opening `gpg` files.